# How to set up dual quadro cards on RHEL 5.5?

Tags: multiple-monitors, redhat-enterprise-linux, nvidia-quadro

I have a RHEL 5 workstation with 2 nvidia Quadro FX4500 cards, with one display attached to each card.

After doing a clean install of RHEL 5.5, the second display doesnt work (it worked ok in RHEL 5.2). Neither separate X screens nor Xinerama are working.

The kernel version is `2.6.18-194.el5`

I've tried nvidia drivers `185.18.36` (the ones that i was using on 5.2) and the latest `260.19.36` and neither works.

My `xorg.conf` is as follows:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 1.0  (buildmeister@builder58)  Fri Aug 14 18:34:43 PDT 2009

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    FontPath        "unix/:7100"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from data in "/etc/sysconfig/keyboard"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
    Option         "XkbLayout" "us"
    Option         "XkbModel" "pc105"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL 3007WFP"
    HorizSync       49.3 - 98.5
    VertRefresh     60.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL 3007WFP"
    HorizSync       49.3 - 98.5
    VertRefresh     60.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro FX 4500"
    BusID          "PCI:10:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro FX 4500"
    BusID          "PCI:129:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

And the Xorg Log:

```
X Window System Version 7.1.1
Release Date: 12 May 2006
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0, Release 7.1.1
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.18-164.11.1.el5 x86_64 Red Hat, Inc.
Current Operating System: Linux blur.svsdsde 2.6.18-194.el5 #1 SMP Tue Mar 16 21:52:39 EDT 2010 x86_64
Build Date: 06 March 2010
Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.1.1-48.76.el5 
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Module Loader present
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Feb 18 09:52:08 2011
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
(**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
(**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
(**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
(**) |-->Screen "Screen1" (1)
(**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor1"
(**) |   |-->Device "Device1"
(**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
(**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
(**) FontPath set to:
    unix/:7100
(==) RgbPath set to "/usr/share/X11/rgb"
(==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules"
(**) Option "Xinerama" "1"
(**) Xinerama: enabled
(==) Max clients allowed: 512, resource mask: 0xfffff
(II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
(II) Module ABI versions:
    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.3
    X.Org Video Driver: 1.0
    X.Org XInput driver : 0.6
    X.Org Server Extension : 0.3
    X.Org Font Renderer : 0.5
(II) Loader running on linux
(II) LoadModule: "bitmap"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/fonts/libbitmap.so
(II) Module bitmap: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 7.1.1, module version = 1.0.0
    Module class: X.Org Font Renderer
    ABI class: X.Org Font Renderer, version 0.5
(II) Loading font Bitmap
(II) LoadModule: "pcidata"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libpcidata.so
(II) Module pcidata: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 7.1.1, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 1.0
(++) using VT number 7

(II) PCI: PCI scan (all values are in hex)
(II) PCI: 00:00:0: chip 10de,005e card 103c,1500 rev a3 class 05,80,00 hdr 00
(II) PCI: 00:01:0: chip 10de,0051 card 103c,1500 rev a3 class 06,01,00 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 00:01:1: chip 10de,0052 card 103c,1500 rev a2 class 0c,05,00 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 00:02:0: chip 10de,005a card 103c,1500 rev a2 class 0c,03,10 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 00:02:1: chip 10de,005b card 103c,1500 rev a3 class 0c,03,20 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 00:04:0: chip 10de,0059 card 103c,1500 rev a2 class 04,01,00 hdr 00
(II) PCI: 00:06:0: chip 10de,0053 card 103c,1500 rev f2 class 01,01,8a hdr 00
(II) PCI: 00:07:0: chip 10de,0054 card 103c,1500 rev f3 class 01,01,85 hdr 00
(II) PCI: 00:08:0: chip 10de,0055 card 103c,1500 rev f3 class 01,01,85 hdr 00
(II) PCI: 00:09:0: chip 10de,005c card 0000,0000 rev a2 class 06,04,01 hdr 01
(II) PCI: 00:0a:0: chip 10de,0057 card 103c,1500 rev a3 class 06,80,00 hdr 00
(II) PCI: 00:0e:0: chip 10de,005d card 0000,0000 rev a3 class 06,04,00 hdr 01
(II) PCI: 00:18:0: chip 1022,1100 card 0000,0000 rev 00 class 06,00,00 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 00:18:1: chip 1022,1101 card 0000,0000 rev 00 class 06,00,00 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 00:18:2: chip 1022,1102 card 0000,0000 rev 00 class 06,00,00 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 00:18:3: chip 1022,1103 card 0000,0000 rev 00 class 06,00,00 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 00:19:0: chip 1022,1100 card 0000,0000 rev 00 class 06,00,00 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 00:19:1: chip 1022,1101 card 0000,0000 rev 00 class 06,00,00 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 00:19:2: chip 1022,1102 card 0000,0000 rev 00 class 06,00,00 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 00:19:3: chip 1022,1103 card 0000,0000 rev 00 class 06,00,00 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 05:05:0: chip 104c,8023 card 103c,1500 rev 00 class 0c,00,10 hdr 00
(II) PCI: 0a:00:0: chip 10de,009d card 10de,02af rev a1 class 03,00,00 hdr 00
(II) PCI: End of PCI scan
(II) PCI-to-ISA bridge:
(II) Bus -1: bridge is at (0:1:0), (0,-1,-1), BCTRL: 0x0008 (VGA_EN is set)
(II) Subtractive PCI-to-PCI bridge:
(II) Bus 5: bridge is at (0:9:0), (0,5,5), BCTRL: 0x0206 (VGA_EN is cleared)
(II) Bus 5 non-prefetchable memory range:
    [0] -1  0   0xf5000000 - 0xf50fffff (0x100000) MX[B]
(II) PCI-to-PCI bridge:
(II) Bus 10: bridge is at (0:14:0), (0,10,10), BCTRL: 0x000a (VGA_EN is set)
(II) Bus 10 I/O range:
    [0] -1  0   0x00003000 - 0x00003fff (0x1000) IX[B]
(II) Bus 10 non-prefetchable memory range:
    [0] -1  0   0xf3000000 - 0xf4ffffff (0x2000000) MX[B]
(II) Bus 10 prefetchable memory range:
    [0] -1  0   0xc0000000 - 0xcfffffff (0x10000000) MX[B]
(II) Host-to-PCI bridge:
(II) Bus 0: bridge is at (0:24:0), (0,0,10), BCTRL: 0x0008 (VGA_EN is set)
(II) Bus 0 I/O range:
    [0] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0x0000ffff (0x10000) IX[B]
(II) Bus 0 non-prefetchable memory range:
    [0] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0xffffffff (0x100000000) MX[B]
(II) Bus 0 prefetchable memory range:
    [0] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0xffffffff (0x100000000) MX[B]
(--) PCI:*(10:0:0) nVidia Corporation Quadro FX 4500 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf3000000/24, 0xc0000000/28, 0xf4000000/24, I/O @ 0x3000/7
(II) Addressable bus resource ranges are
    [0] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0xffffffff (0x100000000) MX[B]
    [1] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0x0000ffff (0x10000) IX[B]
(II) OS-reported resource ranges:
    [0] -1  0   0x00100000 - 0x3fffffff (0x3ff00000) MX[B]E(B)
    [1] -1  0   0x000f0000 - 0x000fffff (0x10000) MX[B]
    [2] -1  0   0x000c0000 - 0x000effff (0x30000) MX[B]
    [3] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0x0009ffff (0xa0000) MX[B]
    [4] -1  0   0x0000ffff - 0x0000ffff (0x1) IX[B]
    [5] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0x000000ff (0x100) IX[B]
(II) Active PCI resource ranges:
    [0] -1  0   0xf5000000 - 0xf5003fff (0x4000) MX[B]
    [1] -1  0   0xf5004000 - 0xf50047ff (0x800) MX[B]

[...snipped... post too long]

    [28] -1 0   0x0000fb00 - 0x0000fbff (0x100) IX[B]
    [29] -1 0   0x00003000 - 0x0000307f (0x80) IX[B](B)
(II) Active PCI resource ranges after removing overlaps:
    [0] -1  0   0xf5000000 - 0xf5003fff (0x4000) MX[B]
    [1] -1  0   0xf5004000 - 0xf50047ff (0x800) MX[B]

[...snipped... post too long]

    [28] -1 0   0x0000fb00 - 0x0000fbff (0x100) IX[B]
    [29] -1 0   0x00003000 - 0x0000307f (0x80) IX[B](B)
(II) OS-reported resource ranges after removing overlaps with PCI:
    [0] -1  0   0x00100000 - 0x3fffffff (0x3ff00000) MX[B]E(B)
    [1] -1  0   0x000f0000 - 0x000fffff (0x10000) MX[B]
    [2] -1  0   0x000c0000 - 0x000effff (0x30000) MX[B]
    [3] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0x0009ffff (0xa0000) MX[B]
    [4] -1  0   0x0000ffff - 0x0000ffff (0x1) IX[B]
    [5] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0x000000ff (0x100) IX[B]
(II) All system resource ranges:
    [0] -1  0   0x00100000 - 0x3fffffff (0x3ff00000) MX[B]E(B)
    [1] -1  0   0x000f0000 - 0x000fffff (0x10000) MX[B]
    [2] -1  0   0x000c0000 - 0x000effff (0x30000) MX[B]
    [3] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0x0009ffff (0xa0000) MX[B]
    [4] -1  0   0xf5000000 - 0xf5003fff (0x4000) MX[B]
    [5] -1  0   0xf5004000 - 0xf50047ff (0x800) MX[B]
    [6] -1  0   0xf5104000 - 0xf5104fff (0x1000) MX[B]
    [7] -1  0   0xf5103000 - 0xf5103fff (0x1000) MX[B]
    [8] -1  0   0xf5102000 - 0xf5102fff (0x1000) MX[B]
    [9] -1  0   0xf5101000 - 0xf5101fff (0x1000) MX[B]
    [10] -1 0   0xfebf0000 - 0xfebf00ff (0x100) MX[B]
    [11] -1 0   0xf5100000 - 0xf5100fff (0x1000) MX[B]
    [12] -1 0   0xf4000000 - 0xf4ffffff (0x1000000) MX[B](B)
    [13] -1 0   0xc0000000 - 0xcfffffff (0x10000000) MX[B](B)
    [14] -1 0   0xf3000000 - 0xf3ffffff (0x1000000) MX[B](B)
    [15] -1 0   0x0000ffff - 0x0000ffff (0x1) IX[B]
    [16] -1 0   0x00000000 - 0x000000ff (0x100) IX[B]
    [17] -1 0   0x000048f0 - 0x000048f7 (0x8) IX[B]
    [18] -1 0   0x000048c0 - 0x000048cf (0x10) IX[B]
    [19] -1 0   0x00004c04 - 0x00004c07 (0x4) IX[B]
    [20] -1 0   0x000048e8 - 0x000048ef (0x8) IX[B]
    [21] -1 0   0x00004c00 - 0x00004c03 (0x4) IX[B]
    [22] -1 0   0x000048e0 - 0x000048e7 (0x8) IX[B]
    [23] -1 0   0x000048b0 - 0x000048bf (0x10) IX[B]
    [24] -1 0   0x000048fc - 0x000048ff (0x4) IX[B]
    [25] -1 0   0x000048d8 - 0x000048df (0x8) IX[B]
    [26] -1 0   0x000048f8 - 0x000048fb (0x4) IX[B]
    [27] -1 0   0x000048d0 - 0x000048d7 (0x8) IX[B]
    [28] -1 0   0x000048a0 - 0x000048af (0x10) IX[B]
    [29] -1 0   0x00004400 - 0x000044ff (0x100) IX[B]
    [30] -1 0   0x00004000 - 0x000040ff (0x100) IX[B]
    [31] -1 0   0x00004840 - 0x0000487f (0x40) IX[B]
    [32] -1 0   0x00004800 - 0x0000483f (0x40) IX[B]
    [33] -1 0   0x00004880 - 0x0000489f (0x20) IX[B]
    [34] -1 0   0x0000fb00 - 0x0000fbff (0x100) IX[B]
    [35] -1 0   0x00003000 - 0x0000307f (0x80) IX[B](B)
(II) LoadModule: "extmod"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
(II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 7.1.1, module version = 1.0.0
    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 0.3
(II) Loading extension SHAPE
(II) Loading extension MIT-SUNDRY-NONSTANDARD
(II) Loading extension BIG-REQUESTS
(II) Loading extension SYNC
(II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
(II) Loading extension XC-MISC
(II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
(II) Loading extension XFree86-Misc
(II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
(II) Loading extension DPMS
(II) Loading extension TOG-CUP
(II) Loading extension Extended-Visual-Information
(II) Loading extension XVideo
(II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
(II) Loading extension X-Resource
(II) LoadModule: "dbe"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
(II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 7.1.1, module version = 1.0.0
    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 0.3
(II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
(II) LoadModule: "glx"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
(II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
(II) NVIDIA GLX Module  185.18.36  Fri Aug 14 18:27:24 PDT 2009
(II) Loading extension GLX
(II) LoadModule: "freetype"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/fonts/libfreetype.so
(II) Module freetype: vendor="X.Org Foundation & the After X-TT Project"
    compiled for 7.1.1, module version = 2.1.0
    Module class: X.Org Font Renderer
    ABI class: X.Org Font Renderer, version 0.5
(II) Loading font FreeType
(II) LoadModule: "type1"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/fonts/libtype1.so
(II) Module type1: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 7.1.1, module version = 1.0.2
    Module class: X.Org Font Renderer
    ABI class: X.Org Font Renderer, version 0.5
(II) Loading font Type1
(II) LoadModule: "record"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
(II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 7.1.1, module version = 1.13.0
    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 0.3
(II) Loading extension RECORD
(II) LoadModule: "dri"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
(II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 7.1.1, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 0.3
(II) Loading sub module "drm"
(II) LoadModule: "drm"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/linux/libdrm.so
(II) Module drm: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 7.1.1, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 0.3
(II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
(II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
(II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
(II) LoadModule: "kbd"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/input/kbd_drv.so
(II) Module kbd: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 7.1.1, module version = 1.1.0
    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 0.6
(II) LoadModule: "mouse"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/input/mouse_drv.so
(II) Module mouse: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 7.1.1, module version = 1.1.1
    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 0.6
(II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  185.18.36  Fri Aug 14 17:51:02 PDT 2009
(II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
(II) Primary Device is: PCI 0a:00:0
(--) Chipset NVIDIA GPU found
(II) Loading sub module "fb"
(II) LoadModule: "fb"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libfb.so
(II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 7.1.1, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.3
(II) Loading sub module "wfb"
(II) LoadModule: "wfb"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
(II) Module wfb: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
    compiled for 7.1.99.2, module version = 1.0.0
(II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
(II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libramdac.so
(II) Module ramdac: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 7.1.1, module version = 0.1.0
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 1.0
(II) resource ranges after xf86ClaimFixedResources() call:
    [0] -1  0   0x00100000 - 0x3fffffff (0x3ff00000) MX[B]E(B)
    [1] -1  0   0x000f0000 - 0x000fffff (0x10000) MX[B]
    [2] -1  0   0x000c0000 - 0x000effff (0x30000) MX[B]
    [3] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0x0009ffff (0xa0000) MX[B]
    [4] -1  0   0xf5000000 - 0xf5003fff (0x4000) MX[B]
    [5] -1  0   0xf5004000 - 0xf50047ff (0x800) MX[B]
    [6] -1  0   0xf5104000 - 0xf5104fff (0x1000) MX[B]
    [7] -1  0   0xf5103000 - 0xf5103fff (0x1000) MX[B]
    [8] -1  0   0xf5102000 - 0xf5102fff (0x1000) MX[B]
    [9] -1  0   0xf5101000 - 0xf5101fff (0x1000) MX[B]
    [10] -1 0   0xfebf0000 - 0xfebf00ff (0x100) MX[B]
    [11] -1 0   0xf5100000 - 0xf5100fff (0x1000) MX[B]
    [12] -1 0   0xf4000000 - 0xf4ffffff (0x1000000) MX[B](B)
    [13] -1 0   0xc0000000 - 0xcfffffff (0x10000000) MX[B](B)
    [14] -1 0   0xf3000000 - 0xf3ffffff (0x1000000) MX[B](B)
    [15] -1 0   0x0000ffff - 0x0000ffff (0x1) IX[B]
    [16] -1 0   0x00000000 - 0x000000ff (0x100) IX[B]
    [17] -1 0   0x000048f0 - 0x000048f7 (0x8) IX[B]
    [18] -1 0   0x000048c0 - 0x000048cf (0x10) IX[B]
    [19] -1 0   0x00004c04 - 0x00004c07 (0x4) IX[B]
    [20] -1 0   0x000048e8 - 0x000048ef (0x8) IX[B]
    [21] -1 0   0x00004c00 - 0x00004c03 (0x4) IX[B]
    [22] -1 0   0x000048e0 - 0x000048e7 (0x8) IX[B]
    [23] -1 0   0x000048b0 - 0x000048bf (0x10) IX[B]
    [24] -1 0   0x000048fc - 0x000048ff (0x4) IX[B]
    [25] -1 0   0x000048d8 - 0x000048df (0x8) IX[B]
    [26] -1 0   0x000048f8 - 0x000048fb (0x4) IX[B]
    [27] -1 0   0x000048d0 - 0x000048d7 (0x8) IX[B]
    [28] -1 0   0x000048a0 - 0x000048af (0x10) IX[B]
    [29] -1 0   0x00004400 - 0x000044ff (0x100) IX[B]
    [30] -1 0   0x00004000 - 0x000040ff (0x100) IX[B]
    [31] -1 0   0x00004840 - 0x0000487f (0x40) IX[B]
    [32] -1 0   0x00004800 - 0x0000483f (0x40) IX[B]
    [33] -1 0   0x00004880 - 0x0000489f (0x20) IX[B]
    [34] -1 0   0x0000fb00 - 0x0000fbff (0x100) IX[B]
    [35] -1 0   0x00003000 - 0x0000307f (0x80) IX[B](B)
(II) resource ranges after probing:
    [0] -1  0   0x00100000 - 0x3fffffff (0x3ff00000) MX[B]E(B)
    [1] -1  0   0x000f0000 - 0x000fffff (0x10000) MX[B]
    [2] -1  0   0x000c0000 - 0x000effff (0x30000) MX[B]
    [3] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0x0009ffff (0xa0000) MX[B]
    [4] -1  0   0xf5000000 - 0xf5003fff (0x4000) MX[B]
    [5] -1  0   0xf5004000 - 0xf50047ff (0x800) MX[B]
    [6] -1  0   0xf5104000 - 0xf5104fff (0x1000) MX[B]
    [7] -1  0   0xf5103000 - 0xf5103fff (0x1000) MX[B]
    [8] -1  0   0xf5102000 - 0xf5102fff (0x1000) MX[B]
    [9] -1  0   0xf5101000 - 0xf5101fff (0x1000) MX[B]
    [10] -1 0   0xfebf0000 - 0xfebf00ff (0x100) MX[B]
    [11] -1 0   0xf5100000 - 0xf5100fff (0x1000) MX[B]
    [12] -1 0   0xf4000000 - 0xf4ffffff (0x1000000) MX[B](B)
    [13] -1 0   0xc0000000 - 0xcfffffff (0x10000000) MX[B](B)
    [14] -1 0   0xf3000000 - 0xf3ffffff (0x1000000) MX[B](B)
    [15] 0  0   0x000a0000 - 0x000affff (0x10000) MS[B]
    [16] 0  0   0x000b0000 - 0x000b7fff (0x8000) MS[B]
    [17] 0  0   0x000b8000 - 0x000bffff (0x8000) MS[B]
    [18] -1 0   0x0000ffff - 0x0000ffff (0x1) IX[B]
    [19] -1 0   0x00000000 - 0x000000ff (0x100) IX[B]
    [20] -1 0   0x000048f0 - 0x000048f7 (0x8) IX[B]
    [21] -1 0   0x000048c0 - 0x000048cf (0x10) IX[B]
    [22] -1 0   0x00004c04 - 0x00004c07 (0x4) IX[B]
    [23] -1 0   0x000048e8 - 0x000048ef (0x8) IX[B]
    [24] -1 0   0x00004c00 - 0x00004c03 (0x4) IX[B]
    [25] -1 0   0x000048e0 - 0x000048e7 (0x8) IX[B]
    [26] -1 0   0x000048b0 - 0x000048bf (0x10) IX[B]
    [27] -1 0   0x000048fc - 0x000048ff (0x4) IX[B]
    [28] -1 0   0x000048d8 - 0x000048df (0x8) IX[B]
    [29] -1 0   0x000048f8 - 0x000048fb (0x4) IX[B]
    [30] -1 0   0x000048d0 - 0x000048d7 (0x8) IX[B]
    [31] -1 0   0x000048a0 - 0x000048af (0x10) IX[B]
    [32] -1 0   0x00004400 - 0x000044ff (0x100) IX[B]
    [33] -1 0   0x00004000 - 0x000040ff (0x100) IX[B]
    [34] -1 0   0x00004840 - 0x0000487f (0x40) IX[B]
    [35] -1 0   0x00004800 - 0x0000483f (0x40) IX[B]
    [36] -1 0   0x00004880 - 0x0000489f (0x20) IX[B]
    [37] -1 0   0x0000fb00 - 0x0000fbff (0x100) IX[B]
    [38] -1 0   0x00003000 - 0x0000307f (0x80) IX[B](B)
    [39] 0  0   0x000003b0 - 0x000003bb (0xc) IS[B]
    [40] 0  0   0x000003c0 - 0x000003df (0x20) IS[B]
(II) Setting vga for screen 0.
(**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
(==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
(==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
(==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
(**) NVIDIA(0): Option "TwinView" "0"
(**) NVIDIA(0): Option "MetaModes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
(**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling RENDER acceleration
(II) NVIDIA(0): Support for GLX with the Damage and Composite X extensions is
(II) NVIDIA(0):     enabled.
(II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU Quadro FX 4500 (G70GL) at PCI:10:0:0 (GPU-0)
(--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 524288 kBytes
(--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 05.70.02.41.01
(II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
(--) NVIDIA(0): Interlaced video modes are supported on this GPU
(--) NVIDIA(0): Connected display device(s) on Quadro FX 4500 at PCI:10:0:0:
(--) NVIDIA(0):     DELL 3007WFP (DFP-0)
(--) NVIDIA(0): DELL 3007WFP (DFP-0): 310.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
(--) NVIDIA(0): DELL 3007WFP (DFP-0): Internal Dual Link TMDS
(II) NVIDIA(0): Assigned Display Device: DFP-0
(II) NVIDIA(0): Validated modes:
(II) NVIDIA(0):     "nvidia-auto-select+0+0"
(II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 2560 x 1600
(--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (101, 101); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
(--) NVIDIA(0):     option
(WW) NVIDIA(0): UBB is incompatible with the Composite extension.  Disabling
(WW) NVIDIA(0):     UBB.
(==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling 32-bit ARGB GLX visuals.
(--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
(II) do I need RAC?  No, I don't.
(II) resource ranges after preInit:
    [0] -1  0   0x00100000 - 0x3fffffff (0x3ff00000) MX[B]E(B)
    [1] -1  0   0x000f0000 - 0x000fffff (0x10000) MX[B]
    [2] -1  0   0x000c0000 - 0x000effff (0x30000) MX[B]
    [3] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0x0009ffff (0xa0000) MX[B]
    [4] -1  0   0xf5000000 - 0xf5003fff (0x4000) MX[B]
    [5] -1  0   0xf5004000 - 0xf50047ff (0x800) MX[B]
    [6] -1  0   0xf5104000 - 0xf5104fff (0x1000) MX[B]
    [7] -1  0   0xf5103000 - 0xf5103fff (0x1000) MX[B]
    [8] -1  0   0xf5102000 - 0xf5102fff (0x1000) MX[B]
    [9] -1  0   0xf5101000 - 0xf5101fff (0x1000) MX[B]
    [10] -1 0   0xfebf0000 - 0xfebf00ff (0x100) MX[B]
    [11] -1 0   0xf5100000 - 0xf5100fff (0x1000) MX[B]
    [12] -1 0   0xf4000000 - 0xf4ffffff (0x1000000) MX[B](B)
    [13] -1 0   0xc0000000 - 0xcfffffff (0x10000000) MX[B](B)
    [14] -1 0   0xf3000000 - 0xf3ffffff (0x1000000) MX[B](B)
    [15] 0  0   0x000a0000 - 0x000affff (0x10000) MS[B]
    [16] 0  0   0x000b0000 - 0x000b7fff (0x8000) MS[B]
    [17] 0  0   0x000b8000 - 0x000bffff (0x8000) MS[B]
    [18] -1 0   0x0000ffff - 0x0000ffff (0x1) IX[B]
    [19] -1 0   0x00000000 - 0x000000ff (0x100) IX[B]
    [20] -1 0   0x000048f0 - 0x000048f7 (0x8) IX[B]
    [21] -1 0   0x000048c0 - 0x000048cf (0x10) IX[B]
    [22] -1 0   0x00004c04 - 0x00004c07 (0x4) IX[B]
    [23] -1 0   0x000048e8 - 0x000048ef (0x8) IX[B]
    [24] -1 0   0x00004c00 - 0x00004c03 (0x4) IX[B]
    [25] -1 0   0x000048e0 - 0x000048e7 (0x8) IX[B]
    [26] -1 0   0x000048b0 - 0x000048bf (0x10) IX[B]
    [27] -1 0   0x000048fc - 0x000048ff (0x4) IX[B]
    [28] -1 0   0x000048d8 - 0x000048df (0x8) IX[B]
    [29] -1 0   0x000048f8 - 0x000048fb (0x4) IX[B]
    [30] -1 0   0x000048d0 - 0x000048d7 (0x8) IX[B]
    [31] -1 0   0x000048a0 - 0x000048af (0x10) IX[B]
    [32] -1 0   0x00004400 - 0x000044ff (0x100) IX[B]
    [33] -1 0   0x00004000 - 0x000040ff (0x100) IX[B]
    [34] -1 0   0x00004840 - 0x0000487f (0x40) IX[B]
    [35] -1 0   0x00004800 - 0x0000483f (0x40) IX[B]
    [36] -1 0   0x00004880 - 0x0000489f (0x20) IX[B]
    [37] -1 0   0x0000fb00 - 0x0000fbff (0x100) IX[B]
    [38] -1 0   0x00003000 - 0x0000307f (0x80) IX[B](B)
    [39] 0  0   0x000003b0 - 0x000003bb (0xc) IS[B]
    [40] 0  0   0x000003c0 - 0x000003df (0x20) IS[B]
(II) NVIDIA(GPU-1): NVIDIA GPU Quadro FX 4500 (G70GL) at PCI:129:0:0 (GPU-1)
(--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): Memory: 524288 kBytes
(--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): VideoBIOS: 05.70.02.41.01
(II) NVIDIA(GPU-1): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
(--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): Interlaced video modes are supported on this GPU
(--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): Connected display device(s) on Quadro FX 4500 at PCI:129:0:0:
(--) NVIDIA(GPU-1):     DELL 3007WFP (DFP-0)
(--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DELL 3007WFP (DFP-0): 310.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
(--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DELL 3007WFP (DFP-0): Internal Dual Link TMDS
(II) NVIDIA(0): Initialized GPU GART.
(II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "nvidia-auto-select+0+0"
(II) Loading extension NV-GLX
(II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA 3D Acceleration Architecture Initialized
(==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
(II) NVIDIA(0): Using the NVIDIA 2D acceleration architecture
(==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store disabled
(==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
(**) Option "dpms"
(**) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
(II) Loading extension NV-CONTROL
(==) RandR enabled
(II) Setting vga for screen 0.
(II) Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
(II) Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
(II) Initializing built-in extension XTEST
(II) Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
(II) Initializing built-in extension XC-APPGROUP
(II) Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
(II) Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
(II) Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
(II) Initializing built-in extension XFree86-Bigfont
(II) Initializing built-in extension RENDER
(II) Initializing built-in extension RANDR
(II) Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
(II) Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
(II) Initializing built-in extension XEVIE
(II) Initializing extension GLX
(WW) Disabling Composite since Xinerama is enabled
(**) Option "CoreKeyboard"
(**) Keyboard0: Core Keyboard
(**) Option "Protocol" "standard"
(**) Keyboard0: Protocol: standard
(**) Option "AutoRepeat" "500 30"
(**) Option "XkbRules" "xorg"
(**) Keyboard0: XkbRules: "xorg"
(**) Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
(**) Keyboard0: XkbModel: "pc105"
(**) Option "XkbLayout" "us"
(**) Keyboard0: XkbLayout: "us"
(**) Option "CustomKeycodes" "off"
(**) Keyboard0: CustomKeycodes disabled
(**) Option "Protocol" "auto"
(**) Mouse0: Device: "/dev/input/mice"
(**) Mouse0: Protocol: "auto"
(**) Option "CorePointer"
(**) Mouse0: Core Pointer
(**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
(**) Option "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
(**) Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
(**) Mouse0: ZAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
(**) Mouse0: Buttons: 9
(II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Mouse0" (type: MOUSE)
(II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Keyboard0" (type: KEYBOARD)
(--) Mouse0: PnP-detected protocol: "ExplorerPS/2"
(II) Mouse0: ps2EnableDataReporting: succeeded
(II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
(II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "nvidia-auto-select+0+0"
(II) Mouse0: ps2EnableDataReporting: succeeded
```

(the snipped part can be changed if necessary)

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Comparing your `xorg.conf` to the one in the *quad screen*, dual Quadro FX4000 system I have access to, I can see the following:

- Your 3rd and 4th screens are (obviously) missing (from the `"ServerLayout"` section and their own `"Monitor"` and `"Screen"` sections), since you only have two screens.
- You are missing some Options in the `"ServerLayout"` sections, the most significant appears to be `"Xinerama" "On"`, yet the log suggests it's on anyway.
- There is a `"Module"` section missing.
- Both cards appear to be present (`"Device0"` & `"Device1"` have different `BusID`s) but there appears to be no `Screen` parameter in their `"Device"` section and no `"Device2"` & `"Device3"` sections. It is possibly that the `Screen` [parameter is only neded if you have multiple monitors on a single card.
- Your `"Screen"` sections have `Option "TwinView" "0"` lines and `Option "Metamodes"`... lines instead of an explicit `Modes` parameter in the `"Display"` sub-section.

My suspicion is that it may be something in one of the `"ServerLayout"` options:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" Above "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
    Screen      3  "Screen3" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "on"
    Option         "Clone" "off"
    Option         "BlankTime" "0"
    Option         "StandbyTime" "0"
    Option         "SuspendTime" "120"
    Option         "OffTime" "180"
EndSection
```

or `"Module"` options:

```
Section "Module"
        Load  "dbe"
        Load  "extmod"
        Load  "fbdevhw"
        Load  "glx"
        Load  "record"
        Load  "freetype"
        Load  "type1"
EndSection
```

You should obviously not need the "Screen 2" and "Screen 3" lines, but it might be worth playing with the others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure if I need screens 2,3 as I only have one display attached to each card. Also I have Xinerama set in the ServerFlags section.
I'll try your settings and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @AlexJ.Roberts - Thanks Alex, I've updated my answer to make the expected differences between our set-ups more obvious.